# here my requirement is this that when user select option from dropdown than that selected value should not visible in another dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, c#-4.0, html-select, webmethod

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  getDetailAmc(investor_id);
  $("#add-amc").on('click', function() {

    count++;
    $("#new-amc-block").append("<div id='div_" + count + "'><div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-4 form-group'><label>Select AMC:</label><select class='form-control Amcselect' id='Amc_select_" + count + "'></select><span class='error hidden' id='Amcselect_error_" + count + "'></span></div><div class='col-sm-4 form-group'><label>Folio No:</label><input type='text' placeholder='Enter Folio Number Here..' class='form-control folionotxt' id='folio_no_" + count + "'><span class='error hidden' id='Foliono_error_" + count + "'></span></div><div class='col-sm-4 form-group'><i class='fa fa-times fa-2x font-icon curs iconcolor deleteamc' title='Delete Amc' id='delete_amc_" + count + "'></i></div></div></div></div>");


    PopulateSelectAmc(AmcArray);
    changesoption();
  });

});

function getDetailAmc(investor_id) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Folio_Mapping1.aspx/getAmc",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      investor_id: investor_id
    }),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnErrorCall
  });

  function OnSuccess(response) {


    var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
    if (result == "") {
      $("#InvId-error").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#InvId-error").text("Invalid Investor Id");
      $(".Amcselect").empty();
    } else {
      $("#InvId-error").addClass("hidden");
      MapAmcDetail(result);

    }

    function MapAmcDetail(result) {
      AmcArray = [];
      AmcArray = $.map(result, function(el) {
        return {
          "AMC_NAME": el.AMC_NAME

        }
      });

      PopulateSelectAmc(AmcArray);

    }

    function PopulateSelectAmc(AmcArray) {

      var option = '';

      option += '<option value="Select">Select AMC</option>';
      for (var i = 0; i < AmcArray.length; i++) {

        option += '<option value="' + AmcArray[i].AMC_NAME + '"id=a_' + i + '">' + AmcArray[i].AMC_NAME + '</option>';
      }

      $('.Amcselect').append(option);

      function changesoption() {
        var value;
        value = $(".Amcselect option:first").val();
        if (value) {
          $(this).data('previous', value);
          $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
        }

        /*  PopulateSelectAmc(AmcArray);*/
        $(".Amcselect").on('change', function() {

          prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
          $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + prevValue + '"]').show();

          value = $(this).val();
          if (value) {
            $(this).data('previous', value);
            $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + value + '"]').hide();
          }

        });
      }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group container margincus">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <label for="investorId">Investor ID:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Invid" placeholder="Enter InvestorId"><span class="error hidden" id="InvId-error"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x font-icon curs" title="Add More Amc" id="add-amc"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
          <label>Select AMC:</label>
          <select class="form-control Amcselect" id="Amc_select_0"></select><span class="error hidden" id="Amcselect_error_0"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
          <label>Enter Folio No:</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Example:1234567891,3456789234...." class="form-control folionotxt" id="folio_no_0"><span class="error hidden" id="Foliono_error_0"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="new-amc-block">

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-default" id="sendemail" type="button">Send Email</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I created plus button to add dropdown as many want and in dropdown options are coming dynamically.here my requirement is this that when user select option from dropdown than that selected value should not visible in another dropdown.I am able to achieve this but problem here I am facing that when user  click plus button and added some dropdown and than select option from dropdown than that selected value not visible in other dropdown which are
Added, but when user  again click plus button and added some dropdown  than all  options are coming into dropdown  so previously selected  option are not hidden from dropdown .

Answer (score 0):

why dont you write a single input (here dropdown change function) something like

```
function RemoveOptionsFromOthers(val){
$('select :not('+this+')').find(option['value="val"]').remove();
}
```

then call the function in all the optionchange event

Comment: no I when I again change my dropdown value than that previous value sholud come into dropdown thats why mine code is working.I just having problem that when i click on add button than again all array value is coming into dropdown